# Coordinate time along trajectory in Schwarzschild metric in general relativity (Schutz, Chapter 11)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

The trajectory of a photon in the Schwarzschild metric is given by

$$
\frac{d\phi}{dr} = ±\frac{1}{r^2}\left[ \frac{1}{b^2} - \frac{1}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right) \right]^{-1/2}.
$$

This can be solved to give

$$
bu = \sin(\phi-\phi_0) + \frac{M}{b}[1-\cos(\phi-\phi_0)]^2 + O\left(\frac{M^2}{b^2}\right)
$$

where $u=1/r$ and this shows that light is bent by a massive object.

I am interested in calculating the rate at which coordinate time elapses if you were to travel on this trajectory. Supposedly this is given by

$$
\frac{dt}{d\phi} = b\left[(bu)^2\left(1-\frac{2M}{b}bu\right)\right]^{-1}.
$$

My question is how do I arrive at this result. I have tried finding it by solving for $\frac{dt}{d\phi}$ in

$$
\frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{dt}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{dr}
$$

where $\frac{dt}{dr}$ comes from the Schwarzschild metric itself,

$$
\frac{dt}{dr} = 1-\frac{2M}{r},
$$

but I was unsuccessful. Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know not just the metric, but how to use conserved quantities in that. The Schwarzchild metric in natural units and considering only equatorial plane $ \vartheta = \pi / 2 $ reads as
$$
( \mathrm d \tau )^2 
= - \left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right )      ( \mathrm d t )^2 
  + \left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right )^{-1} ( \mathrm d r )^2 
  + r^2 ( \mathrm d \varphi )^2
$$
For photons, the proper time $ \tau = 0 $ and thus we cannot use it to parametrise the trajectory. We have to use some affine parameter, say $ \lambda $, which is Schutz's choice. i.e.
$$ \tag{pg}
\left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right ) 
\left ( \frac{\mathrm d t   }{\mathrm d \lambda} \right )^2
=
\left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right )^{-1} 
\left ( \frac{\mathrm d r   }{\mathrm d \lambda} \right )^2
+ r^2 
\left ( \frac{\mathrm d \phi}{\mathrm d \lambda} \right )^2
$$
At this point you have to know how to obtain and relate the conserved quantities to these affine-parametrised ``velocities":
$$ \tag{cq}
L = r^2 \frac{\mathrm d \phi}{\mathrm d \lambda} \qquad \bigwedge \qquad 
E = \left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right ) \frac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d \lambda}
\qquad \bigwedge \qquad b = \frac L E
$$
You need to first substitute Equation (cq) into Equation (pq) to get
$$
\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d \lambda} = \pm \sqrt{ E^2 - \frac{L^2}{r^2} \left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right ) }
$$
and then you apply use Equation (cq) again to get
$$
  \frac{\mathrm d \varphi}{\mathrm d    r   } 
= \frac{\mathrm d \varphi}{\mathrm d \lambda} 
/ \frac{\mathrm d    r   }{\mathrm d \lambda}
= \pm \frac1{r^2} \left [ \frac1{b^2} 
- \frac1{r^2} \left ( 1 - \frac{2M}r \right ) \right ]^{-1/2}
$$
which is your first equation.

This means that the equation you are seeking is obtained by
$$
  \frac{\mathrm d    t   }{\mathrm d \varphi} 
= \frac{\mathrm d    t   }{\mathrm d \lambda} 
/ \frac{\mathrm d \varphi}{\mathrm d \lambda}
$$
which is just a manipulation of the stuff in Equation (cq), and indeed I did manage to get it. I will leave all the filling-in-the-blanks to you. Oh, pq is photon geodesics and cq is conserved quantities, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The last equation you wrote literally gave you the rate of change of $t$ when the curve is parametrised by its radial distance (you are traveling along a null radial geodesic though). You can take it as it is, because solving $r$ in terms of $t$ is doable. Or you can change your parametrisation which is simply the chain rule

Comment: The method you are prescribing will not have gotten what he wanted. Even if he used the solution for $u$ in terms of $\varphi$ that he had, there would be no way to get the relation he wanted because there would be missing factors. One easy way to see why it must fail is to just scrutinise where all the factors of (1-2M/r) is going, and immediately you cannot get the correct power of that.

Comment: @naturallyinconsistent I was under the assumption from OP’s last equation that we are neglecting $\phi$ motion and treating the geodesic as purely radial. If one wants to have varying $\phi$ coming into play certainly this method would fail.

Comment: That is a rather bizarre reading mistake. Not to mention that a purely radial geodesic will necessarily fall into the black hole and never come back out. There would be not much to study.